# Do I need separate Dockerfiles for py2 and py3?

Tags: docker

Currently I have 2 Dockerfiles, `Dockerfile-py2`:

```
FROM python:2.7
# stuff
```

and `Dockerfile-py3`:

```
FROM python:3.4
# stuff
```

where both instances of `# stuff` are identical.

I build two docker images using an invoke task:

```
@task
def docker(ctx):
    """Build docker images.
    """
    tag = ctx.run('git log -1 --pretty=%h').stdout.strip()

    for pyversion in '23':
        name = 'myrepo/myimage{pyversion}'.format(pyversion=pyversion)
        image = '{name}:{tag}'.format(name=name, tag=tag)
        latest = '{name}:latest'.format(name=name)

        ctx.run('docker build -t {image} -f Dockerfile-py{pyversion} .'.format(image=image, pyversion=pyversion))
        ctx.run('docker tag {image} {latest}'.format(image=image, latest=latest))
        ctx.run('docker push {name}'.format(name=name))
```

is there any way to prevent the duplication of `# stuff` so I can't get in a situation where someone edits one file but not the other?

Comment: Perhaps use the `docker-compose.yml` file with two `Dockerfile` for each Python version.

Comment: Since a Docker image packages the application and its runtime together, why do you need both?

Comment: @DavidMaze because these containers are used by the gitlab runner to run unit tests, and since we're transitioning to py3 we need two containers that are identical except for their python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using Dockerfile `ARGS` along with `docker build --build-arg`:

```
ARG version
FROM python:${version}
RUN echo "$(python --version)"
# stuff
```

Now you build for `python2.7` like so:

```
docker build -t myimg/tmp --build-arg version=2.7 .
```

In the output you will see:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN echo "$(python --version)"
 ---> Running in 06e28a29a3d2
Python 2.7.16
```

And in the same way, for `python3.4`:

```
docker build -t myimg/tmp --build-arg version=3.4 .
```

In the output you will see:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN echo "$(python --version)"
 ---> Running in 2283edc1b65d
Python 3.4.10
```

As you can imagine you can also set default values for `${version}` in your `dockerfile`:

```
ARG version=3.4
FROM python:${version}
RUN echo "$(python --version)"
# stuff
```

Now if you just do `docker build -t myimg/tmp .` you will build for `python3.4`. But you can still override with the previous two commands.

So to answer your question, No, you don't need two different docker files.